# Discussion about Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-8.1

Today i got a fantastic news for windows 8.1 released in India . But it's released in US ate yesterday , Anybody know the benefits and features in windows 8.1 ?

and what kind of the difference between windows 8 and windows 8.1 ?

> Is it support android apps ? And just small fun question like,  Have they added start button in windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's quite a few changes, some of which I personally like as I really disliked the feeling of Windows 8 on a normal desktop PC. You should notice some changes as soon as you start using it with some of the changes to the start menu and search functions.

However, seeing as 8.1 has been out for a while, there's a considerable amount of documentation on the web... See a full list of changes [here](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/159803-windows-8-1-a-complete-list-of-changes-and-new-features), and the MSDN release notes of "*What's New*" [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn140266.aspx).

There's no point me regurgitating all the changes, have a look at the links I gave you.

Comment: what about developer side while using windows 8.1.
Is there any way to target app to both Windows 8 & windows 8.1.
Is there any idea.?